# Empty sum of undefined function

Tags: summation, definition

An undergraduate real analysis homework problem I am working on raised the following question:

Does function $f$ need to be defined for $i=0,1$ for empty sum $\sum_{i=1}^0{f(i)}$ to be equal to zero? In other words, do any definitions of the empty sum allow for an empty sum of an undefined function to be calculated?

This problem arises in the calculation of the lower Darboux sum of a function $g:\{0\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Calculating the lower Darboux sum mentioned above using the definition from the textbook "Introduction to Real Analysis" by Manfred Stoll involves finding $\sum_{i=1}^0(m_i*(x_i-x_{i-1}))$, but $x_1$ is not defined, as the only possible partition of the domain of $g$ has one element, $x_0=0$.